# How to make grouped packed circle chart in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So in my dataset, I have 2 columns that I want to show in my chart which is country and name. I want to create a grouped packed circle chart where the grouping is based on country and inside that circle there are circles that represent each name in that country. I followed this and my code is returning nothing and I'm not getting an error either, any help would be appreciated: https://observablehq.com/@clhenrick/circle-packing-grouped-descendants

```
async function bubbleChart() {

    // 1. Access data
    const dataset = await d3.json("./astro.json")
    console.table(dataset[0])

    const width = 450
    const height = 450

    const svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
        .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
    
    const g = svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(2.2)")

    function grouped () {
        const grouped = Array.from(d3.group(data, d => d.country))
        .map(([name, children]) => ({ name, children }));
                
            grouped.forEach(d => {
                d.children.sort(sorter[sort])
            });
              
            return grouped;
    }
    
    const size = 964
    const strokeWidth = 2

    const hierarchy = d3.hierarchy({ children: grouped })
        .sum(d => d.undefined)

    const packed = d3.pack()
        .size([size - strokeWidth * 2, size - strokeWidth * 2])
        .padding(3)(hierarchy);

    const leaf = g.selectAll(".leaf")
        .data(packed.descendants()) // using .descendants() instead of .leaves() draws the parent circles
        .enter().append("g")
        .classed("leaf", true)
        .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x + 1}, ${d.y + 1})`);
          
    const circle = leaf.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 10)
        .attr("fill", "lightblue")
        .attr("stroke", d => d.children ? "#999" : "none")
        .attr("stroke-width", d => d.children ? strokeWidth : 0);
              
    }

bubbleChart()
```

Comment: so sorry i pasted the wrong code, just edited with the correct code I'm struggling with

Comment: no worries, I might get a chance to look tomorrow,  if no one else posts an answer in the meantime

Comment: There are a few things happening in your code, can you share a few example objects from your json to help make sure that an answer works and is most relevant?